# Thingsboard receives no telemaetry after migration from CentOS 8 to Alma 9

Tags: thingsboard

I have a Thingsboard CE running previously on a Cent OS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core) in a virtual box.
Version of Thingsboard = 3.6.1.

Due to the new vision of Cent OS I migrated to Alma Linux.

First step was Alma Linux 8.9.  No problem.

Second step was to Alma Linux release 9.3 (Shamrock Pampas Cat).
Since then, my Thingsboard does not get any telemetry anymore.  No data is received.

Read the logging (/var/log/thingsboard) but I cannot find any ERROR.

If I send a message from with my Chirpstack instance to the mqtt broker, it is received on the thingsboard queue.  Messaging is working.

Can anybody give me a hint what to check ?  Where to look ?

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue after updating to 3.6.1. Entities attributes were returned as expected but timeseries data was not returned unless it was live data (updated while the WebSocket subscription is active).

I did not manage deployment of the ThingsBoard server but the team in charge told me that they had to switch to another DB system (probably from PostgreSQL+TimescaleDB to PostgreSQL+Cassandra).